# React Native/Xcode Release with Typescript not working

Tags: typescript, react-native, release

I’m trying to build a release version of my RN/Typescript project to iOS. I have updated my “Bundle React Native code and images” to the following:

```
    export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh /artifacts/index.ios.js
```

But I still get the following error on Xcode, although the `index.ios.js` does seem to be there.

> Expected path `/artifacts/index.ios.js` to be relative to one of the
>   project roots

Would love for some help...

Answer (score 0):

Removing the first `/` before `artifacts` solved the problem:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh artifacts/index.ios.js
```